# Pass a generic list to a fuction and sort it (.Net Framework 4.8)

Tags: c#

I have this function:

```
private void ReadFilesCommon<T>(string path, List<Class> Data, IParser Iparser, Func<KeyValuePair<string, object>, T> ClassCreator)
        {
            foreach (List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> entry in Iparser.ParseFiles(path)) // Files
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry2 in entry)
                {
                    Data.Add(ClassCreator(entry2));
                }
            }

            Data.Sort(delegate (Class t1, Class t2)
            {return (t1.name.CompareTo(t2.name));});

            
            return;
        }
```

Being Class the variable.

I want to make a function that can receive a list of some class (that has .name in it) and be able to sort it.

The problem is, if i make it generic, it loses the .name, so i can't sort it.

Comment: Have you looked into using linq for sorting needs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/sorting-data

Comment: but i can't sort it because it's generic

Comment: have you tried to make an abstract class and add `name` property to it (and ofc inherit from it), and then filter your  generic argument using `where T : MyAbsClass` ? this way you have .name in your list

Comment: In order to retain the `name` property, you need to [limit the types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) that can be used.  
Typically, this kind of constraint is enforced using an [`Interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces) or an [`abstract` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract).

Comment: I'm not really well versed with abstracting in c#, try giving a answer

Comment: What about adding an additional parameter for `Comparison<T>` and you just plug that into your `Data.Sort(Comparison<T> Value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either introduce an interface (or abstract class) which will expose the `name` property, implement it in the corresponding classes and restrict generic type to it via [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```cs
public class IHaveName
{
   public string name {get; set;}
} 

private void ReadFilesCommon<T>(string path, 
    List<T> Data, 
    IParser Iparser, 
    Func<KeyValuePair<string, object>, T> ClassCreator) where T : IHaveName
{
    // ...
}
```

Or provide extra parameter which will represent function returning the sort field, depending on how generic you want it be it can be just `string` or another generic parameter:

```cs
private void ReadFilesCommon<T>(string path, 
    List<T> Data, 
    IParser Iparser, 
    Func<KeyValuePair<string, object>, T> ClassCreator, 
    Func<T, string> sortBy
)
{
    // ...
    Data.Sort(delegate (T t1, T t2)
            {return (sortBy(t1).CompareTo(sortBy(t2)));});
}
```

And usage looking something like `ReadFilesCommon(..., t => t.name)`.

P.S. I recommend to follow [standard naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions).

Comment: but still... how do i do the sorting?

Comment: @Filipe in first case you sort as you did before, in the second - you should substitute property accessor (`.name`) with wrapping the instance in `sortBy(...)`

Comment: @Filipe fixed - use generic type parameter name (`T`).

Comment: what ```sortBy()``` does?

Comment: @Filipe returns the value to use for sorting. It is a function call via `Func` [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates).

Comment: it says the method is not defined

Comment: @Filipe have you added it to parameter list of the `ReadFilesCommon` method?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your `List<Class>` type. I think you might be confused about generics, but that's just me. But I hope this helps:

I would classes implement `IComparable`:

```
void ReadFilesCommon<T>(...) where T : IComparable
{
    ...
    // you don't need delegate
    data.Sort();
}
```

..or pass in `IComparer` (or your delegate) as an additional argument:

```
void ReadFilesCommon<T>(... ICopmarer<T> comparer)
{
    ...
    data.Sort(comparer);
}
```

See [List.Sort docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort(system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))) for more.